# Increasing aws log download speed

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, download

I'm going to start with showing the code and then what I'm trying to do, code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

var (
    // empty strings for security reasons
    Bucket         = ""                                               // Download from this bucket
    Prefix         = "" // Using this key prefix
    LocalDirectory = "s3logs"                                                    // Into this directory
)

func main() {
    sess := session.New()
    client := s3.New(sess, &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-1")})
    params := &s3.ListObjectsInput{Bucket: &Bucket, Prefix: &Prefix}

    manager := s3manager.NewDownloaderWithClient(client, func(d *s3manager.Downloader) {
        d.PartSize = 64 * 1024 * 1024 // 64MB per part
        d.Concurrency = 8
    }) // works

    //manager := s3manager.NewDownloaderWithClient(client) //works

    d := downloader{bucket: Bucket, dir: LocalDirectory, Downloader: manager}

    client.ListObjectsPages(params, d.eachPage)

}

type downloader struct {
    *s3manager.Downloader
    bucket, dir string
}

func (d *downloader) eachPage(page *s3.ListObjectsOutput, more bool) bool {
    for _, obj := range page.Contents {
        d.downloadToFile(*obj.Key)
    }

    return true
}

func (d *downloader) downloadToFile(key string) {
    // Create the directories in the path
    file := filepath.Join(d.dir, key)

    if err := os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(file), 0775); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Downloading " + key)
    // Setup the local file
    fd, err := os.Create(file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer fd.Close()

    // Download the file using the AWS SDK
    fmt.Printf("Downloading s3://%s/%s to %s...\n", d.bucket, key, file)
    params := &s3.GetObjectInput{Bucket: &d.bucket, Key: &key}
    _, e := d.Download(fd, params)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
```

}

I'm trying to download the log files from a particular bucket and eventually many buckets.  I need the download to be as fast as possible because.  There is lots of data. My question is what is the most effective way to download huge amounts of data quickly?  The whole process is nil if those logs can't be downloaded at a reasonable speed.  Is there a faster way, it's already concurrent according to amazons doc?  Any ideas?  Also, i've noticed a curious thing.  It doesn't matter if I set the Concurrency to 1, 4, or 20.  Everything is still downloading at ~.70 - ~/.80 gb / min

Comment: 700-800GB/min equals to 100Mb/s. Pretty common _bandwidth limit_. Can your machine handle more?

Comment: Yeah it can handle more, still the Concurrency should be doing something.  What's the point of setting a Concurrency is 1 core performs just as well as 4. For that matter I'd wrap it in python for the same speed. Ultimately I could run this script on an aws instance with a huge number of cores. Also, I said it was pulling .80gb/min, so less than 1gb per minute.  I would love to have 700gbs/min lol

Comment: Sure, a typo on my side, GB should read MB. A little bit more of context might be helpful with solving this – for example number of log files you're trying to fetch, average size and ec2 machine type. AFAIR my t2.small could handle around this kind of traffic from S3, with very high concurrency, but for relatively small files (~70kB). I don't think number of cores actually matters as this would be an IO bound process. Although concurrency in terms of number of connections could – mainly when dealing with small files.

Comment: Many log files over many buckets, whose file size is variable on traffic. A days worth of data is well over 5gb on a per bucket level. I need these files to do stats on the impressions. There was this one script on github I came across that claimed to have a download speed of 1gb per second.  I don't need that much speed, but I do need a bump to do things with this data. Now was far as I know I should be able to download each file concurrently. I'm not seeing a speed increase no matter how many cores I devote. Given what the other scripts bench marks are I know there is run for improvement.